# react-yandex-maps получение ближайших координат относительно маркера

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Собственно проблема следующая, документация react ya map - на редкость не очень хорошая. Необходимо получить координаты ближайшей точки на мкаде относительно поставленного маркера. Полигон соответственно создан, необходимо вызвать какой то метод. Есть метод getClosestPoint у YMaps, но вызвать его не получается... Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь друзья! Спасибо.

```
   import { YMaps, Map, Placemark, Polygon } from 'react-yandex-maps';
     
       class YMap extends React.Component {
            state = {
                marker: [],
                markerAddress: "",
            }
            ymaps: any
            polygon: any
        
            geocode() { // получаем адрес по координатам установленного маркера и отображаем в нотификейшене.
                this.ymaps.geocode(this.state.marker)
                    .then((result: any) => this.setState({ markerAddress: result.geoObjects.get(0).getAddressLine() }))
                    .then(() => {
                        store.addNotification({ // создаем нотификейшн
                            title: "Address",
                            message: this.state.markerAddress,
                            type: "info",
                            insert: "top",
                            container: "top-right",
                            animationIn: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeIn"],
                            animationOut: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeOut"],
                            dismiss: {
                                duration: 5000,
                                onScreen: true
                            }
                        })
                    })
            }
        
        
            render() {
                return (
                    <YMaps
                        query={{ apikey: 'My-Api-Key' }}
                        >
                        <ReactNotification />
                        <Map
                            modules={['geocode']}
                            defaultState={{ center: [55.75, 37.57], zoom: 9 }}
                            width={"100%"}
                            height={"100vh"}
                            onClick={(event: any) => { // устанавливаем маркер и записываем координаты в стейт
                                this.setState({ marker: event.get('coords') })
                                this.geocode() // отображаем адрес
                            }}
                            onLoad={(ymaps: any) => this.ymaps = ymaps}
                        >
                            <Polygon
        
                                geometry={moscow.coordinates} // координаты в файлике json.
                                options={{ visible: false }}
                            />
                            {this.state.marker &&
                                <Placemark
                                    geometry={this.state.marker}
                                />}
                        </Map>
                    </YMaps>
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в инстансе полигона нашел метод getCloses(), это не getClosesPoint(), однако возвращает тоже ближайшую точку! Похоже на решение проблемы.
В конечном итоге выглядит так:

```
<Polygon
instanceRef={(ref) => this.polygonInst = ref}
geometry={moscow.coordinates}
options={{ visible: false }}
/>
console.log(this.polygonInst.geometry.getClosest(this.state.marker))
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пользоваться методами яндекс карт вам нужно взять `instanceRef` у вашей карты (описание: https://react-yandex-maps.now.sh/map)

```
<Map defaultState={{ center: [50, 20], zoom: 10, controls: ['zoom'] }} width="100%" height="100%" instanceRef={ref => (this.myMap = ref)} />
```

далее вы в `this.myMap` уже можете пользоваться методами яндекс карт

Comment: Уже пробовал. Все равно получаю на выходе setClosestPoint is not a function :(

Comment: уже второй день копаюсь в объекте Map и не могу найти нужный мне метод в нем. Я в отчаянии честно говоря, из за такой глупости застрял на одном месте